# Wordpress featured images not showing up in IE8

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a problem with IE8: It doesn't shows featured images on this website: http://www.melisayavas.com/news/

This is the code in my functions.php used to output the featured images:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' )) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}

if ( function_exists('add_image_size')) {
    add_image_size('news-thumb', 200, 200);
}
```

This is the CSS used for the featured-images:

```
.post-thumb {
    float: left; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Specifically for IE8 I have this CSS:

```
.post-thumb img {
    float: left\9;
    margin-top: 10px\9;
    margin-right: 10px\9;
}
```

If I add margin or width to the `.post-thumb element`, the image shows up on IE8 but I don't need a fixed width or height. I don't understand why it doesn't pick up the image width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by this rule:

```
img, object, embed {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

If you remove the `img` from this rule, the image will appear in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will render as `<img width="118" height="200"`

There is no `px` with the `width` and `height`. But by the properties of Chrome and Firefox, It will automatically read as `width="118px" height="200px"`.

But IE doesn't have this inbuilt property. Thats why it is not showing your image.

Try Updating your code to add `px` to the image size.