# IE8 Wordpress Thumbnails > add px to $hwstring

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8

WordPress renders thumbnails with these attributes:

```
<img width="100" height="200" ...
```

IE7\8 requires is this:

```
<img width="100px" height="200px" ...
```

(exact problem is here: [Wordpress featured images not showing up in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573458/wordpress-featured-images-not-showing-up-in-ie8))

I digged into the core and found the code where the height\width is rendered:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L223

my question:
Can you please help me with a custom function to add the **px** part into the $hwstring (function is here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/media.php#L98 )

thanks in advance for every tip.

Comment: Why don't you use the filter, 'get_image_tag' and adjust the dimensions within that? $html = apply_filters( 'get_image_tag', $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size );

Comment: thx for your input.I`m currently trying to do that with trial and error method :-/ http://pastebin.com/21SBphXf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
function custom_dimensions($html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size){
    $html = preg_replace('%(width|height)(="[0-9]{1,4})(")%', '$1$2px$3', $html);
    return $html;
}

add_filter('get_image_tag', 'custom_dimensions',1, 6);
```

I've only quickly tested it out at my end.

Comment: the preg_replace works perfectly. thanks for the snippet. However the function does not kick in. I tried with apply_filters, with different priority. no success. We cannot get into the "function image_hwstring" directly  without any hook right?

Comment: The filter seemed to work for me when inserting an image into the content editor. It wont work retrospectively on any existing content.

Comment: Doesn't look like the image_hwstring takes any filters. So I guess you are left with the above filter, moving to a jquery method or using the image_to_editor filter to intercept any image insertions into the editor.

Comment: oh yeah it works perfect when I re-add a few images. Why I haven't tried that?!?  as you said - it doesn't work on existing content (I was always refreshing images added before the new filter was active.) Thank you very much for your help and the solution.

Comment: No problem. If you need to make this change to existing content, jQuery would be the way to go.